# java and spring and eclipse jpa persistence provider

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jpa

In jpa configuration for LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean i used `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` as my PersistenceProvider but now after upgrading java and spring it seems that eclipse uses a `jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` and spring expects a `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` and while the two classes are the same it appears to be a compilation error
any suggestions on what to do ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the current Spring Version (5.3.X) - more specifically org.springframework.orm.jpa - does not yet support the jakarta.persistence package as it only depends on javax.persistence.